# Keep receiving 503 error while scraping with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape fanfiction.net with rvest and keep getting the 503 server error.
The robots.txt file allows to scrape the site with a delay of 5 seconds, the "Terms of Service" only forbid it for commercial use, whereas I am intending to use it for research purposes (Digital Literary Studies here).
The following chunk of code results in an error already:

```
library (httr)
library (rvest)
url <- "https://www.fanfiction.net"
userAgent <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"
read_html(url, user_agent(userAgent))
```

Most of the advice regarding that error recommends incorporating a delay between scraping requests, or providing a user agent.
Since I get the error from the first URL, incorporating a delay doesn't seem to solve the problem.

I provided different user agents:

- "Mozilla/5.0"
- agents of the "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0" sort, but the server seems to react to the brackets and the long version gives me a 403 error.
- Finally, I provided my institution, name and email address as a user agent, and once (!!) received a 200 status code.

What would be the next step?

Comment: Good of you to mention the `robots.txt` limits and ToS details, commonly overlooked (and/or abused). Thank you for that.

Comment: Perhaps related (just bad-luck timing), they are apparently in a migration process: *"We are in the final stage of server migration which will allow us to provide a more stable service in the immediate future."* 503s can be caused by several things, it would make sense if the migration is hitting pain-points or glitching a little, that you'd be seeing 503s. Perhaps wait a bit and try again?

Comment: Thanks for the info, there might be something to it! Standard browsing is no issue though and I've been trying for the past week...